# oracle plsql aggregate error: ORA-06502: character string buffer too small

Tags: oracle, plsql, aggregate, ora-06502

i wrote a simple aggregate function that should work on columns with csv text in them by aggregating distinct values in a resulting csv string. the functions seems to work all the way to the end when it craps out with the ORA-06502 error right when it should be returning the result.

here is the code:

type def:

```
create or replace type array_union_typ as object (

union_agg nvarchar2(1000),

static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx  in out array_union_typ)
                return number,

member function ODCIAggregateIterate   (self  in out array_union_typ,
                                        value in nvarchar2)
                return number,

member function ODCIAggregateTerminate (self         in array_union_typ,
                                        return_value out nvarchar2,
                                        flags        in number)
                return number,

member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self in out array_union_typ,
                                   ctx2 in array_union_typ)
                return number,

static function agg_union(arg1 in nvarchar2,
                          arg2 in nvarchar2)
                return nvarchar2
);
```

the body:

```
create or replace type body array_union_typ  is

static function ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx in out array_union_typ
                                     ) return number is
begin
    sctx := array_union_typ(null);
    return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateIterate(self in out array_union_typ,
                                     value in nvarchar2
                                     ) return number is
begin
    union_agg := array_union_typ.agg_union(union_agg, value);
    return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateTerminate(self in array_union_typ,
                                       return_value out nvarchar2,
                                       flags in number
                                       ) return number is
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('result: '''|| union_agg || ''', length:' || length(union_agg)); --this still prints
    return_value := self.union_agg; -- <-- this is where the error is indicated
    --return_value := 'x'; -- returning this still gives the error.
    return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

member function ODCIAggregateMerge(self in out array_union_typ,
                                   ctx2 in array_union_typ
                                   ) return number is
begin
    union_agg := array_union_typ.agg_union(union_agg, ctx2.union_agg);
    return ODCIConst.Success;
end;

static function agg_union(arg1 in nvarchar2,
                          arg2 in nvarchar2)
                return nvarchar2 is
    result nvarchar2(1000);
    orig nvarchar2(1000);
begin
    dbms_output.enable;
    orig := replace(arg1||','||arg2, chr(0));

    FOR rec IN (SELECT DISTINCT(regexp_substr(orig, '[^,]+', 1, level)) AS a
           FROM dual CONNECT BY regexp_substr(orig, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL ORDER BY a) LOOP
      IF result IS NOT NULL THEN
        result := result || ',' || rec.a;
      ELSE
        result := rec.a;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    --dbms_output.put_line('endwith: ''' || result || '''');
    RETURN substr(result,1,1000);
end;
end;
```

here is a test table and data:

```
SQL> desc uniontest
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 I                                                  NVARCHAR2(50)

SQL> select * from uniontest;

I
--------------------------------------------------
a
a
b,c
b,d,e
```

and finally, this is what happens if i try to use the aggregate function:

```
SQL> select array_union(i) from uniontest;
select array_union(i) from uniontest
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "M35456.ARRAY_UNION_TYP", line 25


result: 'a,b,c,d,e', length:9
```

if i simply pass a single character string like 'x' in the offending line, i still get the same error. only on a null result does it go away. i am stumped and out of ideas.

thanks for any help.

btw, if anyone has any idea why i get added \0 characters i my agg_union function parameters, i am dying to know about that, too.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with `nvarchar2`; this works if those are just changed to `varchar2`. I can't see an obvious workaround as it looks internal rather than something you're doing. You might be able to kludge something with CLOBs instead; or de-aggregate the values and then pass the distinct values to `listagg`, if you have it available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ODCIaggregate` methods don't seem to be playing nicely with `nvarchar2`; you don't appear to be doing anything wrong since it works fine if those are all changed to `varchar2`.

If you are on 11gR2 and thus have the `listagg` function available - but currently aren't using that because you need to figure out the distinct values - you can combine it with your existing `regexp_substr` function, so you don't need your own type/function:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LISTAGG(a, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a), chr(0), '')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT(regexp_substr(i, '[^,]+', 1, level)) AS a
    FROM uniontest CONNECT BY regexp_substr(i, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY a
);
```

... which with your data gives:

```
REPLACE(LISTAGG(A,',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYA),CHR(0),'')
------------------------------------------------------
a,b,c,d,e
```

In earlier versions you can use `SELECT REPLACE(WM_CONCAT(a), chr(0), '')` instead.

(The `chr(0)` here and the `\0` in your question seem to be related to `nvarchar2`, but someone else will need to chip in on the details...)

Comment: Thank you, the change from `nvarchar2` to `varchar2` did it. Also using `listagg` will make the code a bit better. not that anyone but me will see it. hopefully i will not have to use this on strings with accented characters.

Comment: @JoeDemarco - the `listagg` version seems to work with the table column still defined as `nvarchar2`, so I'd have thought it would cope with accented characters - haven't tested that though.

Comment: yeah, the aggregation might work but you'd still have to return the string, at which point it gets shoehorned into a `varchar2` and all kinds of hilarity ensue. usually resulting in rapid hair loss.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(regexp_substr(orig, '[^,]+', 1, level)) AS a
       FROM dual CONNECT BY regexp_substr(orig, '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL ORDER BY a)
```

results in an infinite number of rows, since the `CONNECT BY` condition is not dependend on the row.

Since you loop over the result appending characters to a string sooner the string becomes to large.

Comment: you can just try running it then and you will see that it if fact does what i want and the result gets returned by that function properly. in fact this part i have changed from a more conventional string search/loop approach way after i started dealing with this error. also, in the test run i have posted you can see that the `dbms_output.put_line` in `ODCIAggregateTerminate` displays its output just befor the error: `result: 'a,b,c,d,e', length:9`.